# do subtraction from two list

Tags: python-2.7, list

I have 2 two lists like:
1:

```
[[113, 3528.27], [114, 4376.139999999999], [116, 4328.85], [124, 390.27], [127, 814.12]]
```

2:

```
[[113, 1237], [114, 4422], [116, 1245], [124, 324], [127, 242]]
```

I want to match the first element in each sublist, and do subtraction for the second element in the sublist. I used simple loop as:

```
for i in 1:
  for j in 2:
     if i == j:
        i[1] - j[1]
```

is there a fast way to make it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you provide a correct/reproducible example? (variable name cannot start with numbers, for example; plus the loop doesn't make sense)

Comment: Assuming you mean you want to join by i[0] == j[0] and project i[1] - j[1], it might be more efficient to convert your lists to dictionaries and join by key.

Comment: @ImDarrenG thanks for the answer. I prefer to see any efficient way with list operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for:

```
a = [[113, 3528.27], [114, 4376.139999999999], [116, 4328.85], [124, 390.27], [127, 814.12]]
b = [[113, 1237], [114, 4422], [116, 1245], [124, 324], [127, 242]]
c = [[x[0], x[1] - y[1]] for x, y in zip(a, b)]
```

Comment: Hey @zipa, thank you for your answer. your answer is awesome, but I need the correlated first element in the same sublist: as [[113,2291.27], [114,-45.8600],...]

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit hard to interpret. Maybe some expected output would have made the difference. 
However, this is what I interpreted it to mean.

```
def sub_two_lists(list1, list2):
    sublist = []
    mainlist = []
    for i in list1:
        for j in list2:
            if i[0] == j[0]:
                sublist.append(i[0])
                susblist.append(i[1] - j[1])
        mainlist.append(sublist)
        sublist = []
    return mainlist

list1 = [[113, 3528.27], [114, 4376.139999999999], [116, 4328.85], [124, 390.27], [127, 814.12]]
list2 = [[113, 1237], [114, 4422], [116, 1245], [124, 324], [127, 242]]
print(sub_two_lists(list1, list2))
```

> **Expected output**: [[113, 2291.27], [114, -45.86000000000058], [116,
>   3083.8500000000004], [124, 66.26999999999998], [127, 572.12]]